# Working demo for screensharing in react-native-webrtc

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, screensharing, react-native-webrtc

Can anybody share a working demo for screensharing in react-native-webrtc?
I was trying to implement the same but I was not able to display the `displayStream` into the remote peers.
The `displayStream.toURL()` was throwing an exception and it reads as `toURL()` is undefined. But the streaming works for the source not for the other peers. I am passing the displayStream from the source in an event to the other peers.
Please share any working code or share some ideas on how to fix this problem

Thanks in advance